# How to clean the data to get Yes if it exists and No if it doesn't exists?

Tags: mysql

I am working on a query to get the following data clean with the following conditions.

By checking each entries, if customer_ID, Agent & Order Dates are identical, and one of the entries is having signature = 'Yes', then return 'Yes, else 'No'. Is it possible to clean it by sql query without clean it manually after export the data?

**Sample of the data:**

```
  Customber_ID|Agent|Order Date|Signature
  1      | Angie | 2019-02-27 | No
  1      | Angie | 2019-02-27 | No
  1      | Angie | 2019-02-27 | Yes
  1      | Angie | 2019-02-27 | No
  2      | Roy   | 2019-02-27 | No
  2      | Roy   | 2019-02-27 | No
```

**The cleaned data that I want:**

```
  Customber_ID|Agent|Order Date|Signature
  1      | Angie | 2019-02-27 | Yes
  2      | Roy   | 2019-02-27 | No
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service. Please edit your question so as to include what you've tried so far and what error you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

How about a summing function with some conditionals?:

```
SELECT ...
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Signature = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 
        THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS Signature
...
GROUP BY Customber_ID
```